# ScrollView doesn't work in RefreshView .net Maui

Tags: xaml, xamarin, scrollview, maui

I have a ScrollView in my .net Maui application. It contains a RefreshView with a CollectionView. It worked fine but yesterday it doesn't scroll anymore.

Here a video of the issue: https://de.files.fm/u/3rhsdu786

I tested the ScrollView with some Frames and it worked, so there must be a problem with the RefreshView or with the combination. I also tried to create a new page and inserted the old code but it also didn't work.
Here is my xaml code:

```
<ScrollView>
        <StackLayout>
            <!--Der Frame ist Visible, wenn für den Tag eine für den Schüler betreffende Nachricht existiert ansonsten bleibt diese Nachricht unsichtbar-->
            <Button Text="Neue Nachrichten unter Aktuelles!" Command="{Binding OnMessage}" IsVisible="{Binding IsVisibleInfo}" CornerRadius="30" Margin="0,15,0,0" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

            <Frame IsVisible="{Binding IsVisibleNoAlert}" HorizontalOptions="Center" BackgroundColor="Transparent">
                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start" HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <Label Text="Keine Vertretung!" FontSize="Title" HorizontalTextAlignment="Center" VerticalOptions="Start" Margin="10"/>
                    <Label Text="Heute hast du keine Vertretung. Dein Tag findet ganz normal statt." HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"/>
                    <Label Text="{Binding Status}" HorizontalOptions="Center" Margin="20" TextColor="Gray" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" IsVisible="{Binding IsVisibleNoAlert}"/>
                </StackLayout>
            </Frame>

            <RefreshView x:DataType="vm:TodayViewModel" Command="{Binding LoadStandInsCommand}" IsRefreshing="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}" IsEnabled="{Binding RefreshIsEnabled}" Margin="30,10,30,30">
                <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Status}" HorizontalOptions="Center" TextColor="Gray" VerticalOptions="StartAndExpand" IsVisible="{Binding IsVisibleView}"/>
                    <CollectionView ItemsSource="{Binding StandIns}" SelectionMode="None" IsVisible="{Binding IsVisibleView}">
                        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <StackLayout x:DataType="model:StandIn" Margin="0,10,0,10">
                                    <Frame HeightRequest="110" BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource WhiteMode2nd}, Dark={StaticResource DarkMode2nd}}" BorderColor="{Binding Color}" CornerRadius="10">
                                        <StackLayout Margin="-20" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                            <Line BackgroundColor="{Binding Color}" HeightRequest="170" WidthRequest="5" HorizontalOptions="Start"/>
                                            <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="10,5,10,5">
                                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                                                    <RowDefinition Height="0.75*"/>
                                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.7*"/>
                                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="0.3*"/>
                                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                                <Label Text="{Binding Stunde}" Style="{StaticResource LableStyleStandIn}"  Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
                                                <Label Text="{Binding Fach}" Style="{StaticResource LableStyleStandIn}" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                                <Label Text="{Binding Art}" FontSize="17" Style="{StaticResource LableStyleStandIn}" Grid.Row="2"/>
                                                <Label Text="{Binding Raum}" Style="{StaticResource LableStyleStandIn}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                                <Label Text="{Binding Lehrer}" FontSize="17" Style="{StaticResource LableStyleStandIn}" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"/>
                                            </Grid>
                                        </StackLayout>
                                    </Frame>
                                </StackLayout>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    </CollectionView>
                </StackLayout>
            </RefreshView>
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <!--Der Button um in die Refreshview entweder die Vertretung für heute oder morgen zu laden-->
    <Frame Style="{StaticResource ButtonStyleSwitchDay}" >
        <Grid Margin="-15">
            <Button Command="{Binding ChangeSide}" Background="Transparent" BorderColor="Transparent"/>
            <Image Source="{Binding ButtonImageDay}"/>
        </Grid>
    </Frame>
</Grid>
```

The ViewModel workes fine, so there is no problem with it.

Thanks for helping me.

Comment: I think your nesting is not right. The RefreshView should be on the outside and should contain a scrollable View as a child: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/refreshview?view=net-maui-7.0 You have it the other way around.

Comment: @ewerspej You are right. Thanks. But do you have any idea why it worked before and then stopped. Do you want to write an answer?

Comment: I find it strange that it worked before, if the code was already exactly like that before the problems started. For an answer, I'd have to reproduce and fix the problem or at least get a better overview. Maybe if I find time later, but no promises.

Comment: @ewerspej Yes it was exacly the same code. No problem you don't have to reproduce it.  I was just interessted if you know it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credits: ewerspej

`RefreshView` must be on the outside and `ScrollView` on the inside like below:

`````
<RefreshView >
    <ScrollView>
     
        ````
    </ScrollView>
</RefreshView>
`````

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/refreshview?view=net-maui-7.0