# Do I need to rewrite all of my XAML when migrating from .NET MAUI 6 to .NET MAUI 7?

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, mobile, maui

I've been writing an app in .NET MAUI 6 for some time. Due to needing some resourcing regarding maps controls I updated to .NET MAUI 7.

Here is the page when running in .NET MAUI 6:

[image]

Here's the same XAML when running .NET MAUI 7:

[image]

As you can see there's a drastic difference in how the controls are rendered.

This is the XAML (the same) for both pages:

```
<ContentPage
x:Class="Xen.Presentation.App.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
Shell.FlyoutBehavior="Disabled"
Shell.NavBarIsVisible="False">

<ScrollView>
    <RefreshView
        Command="{Binding RefreshCommand}"
        IsRefreshing="{Binding IsRefreshing}"
        VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <StackLayout>
            <Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                <Image
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.RowSpan="5"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                    Aspect="AspectFit"
                    Source="background_image.jpg" />

                <StackLayout
                    Grid.Row="0"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
                    Margin="0,25,0,0"
                    Orientation="Horizontal"
                    VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Frame
                        BackgroundColor="Transparent"
                        CornerRadius="20"
                        HeightRequest="40"
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                        WidthRequest="40">
                        <Image
                            Aspect="AspectFit"
                            HeightRequest="40"
                            Source="heartfullicon.png"
                            WidthRequest="40" />
                    </Frame>

                    <Frame
                        Padding="0"
                        BackgroundColor="White"
                        CornerRadius="100"
                        HeightRequest="150"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        VerticalOptions="Start"
                        WidthRequest="150">
                        <Image
                            Aspect="AspectFill"
                            HeightRequest="150"
                            Source="cloudprofile.jpg"
                            WidthRequest="150" />
                    </Frame>

                    <Frame
                        BackgroundColor="White"
                        CornerRadius="20"
                        HeightRequest="40"
                        HorizontalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                        VerticalOptions="Center"
                        WidthRequest="40">
                        <Image
                            Aspect="AspectFit"
                            BackgroundColor="Black"
                            HeightRequest="40"
                            Source="heartfullicon.png"
                            WidthRequest="40" />
                    </Frame>
                </StackLayout>

                <Label
                    Grid.Row="1"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="3"
                    FontAttributes="Bold"
                    FontSize="Title"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    Text="Emily Watson"
                    TextColor="White"
                    VerticalOptions="Center" />

                <Label
                    Grid.Row="2"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
                    FontSize="Body"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    Text="Statistical Analysis and Data Reconfiguration"
                    TextColor="White"
                    VerticalOptions="Center" />

                <Label
                    Grid.Row="3"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
                    Margin="15,0,15,0"
                    FontSize="Small"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    HorizontalTextAlignment="Center"
                    LineBreakMode="WordWrap"
                    MaxLines="3"
                    Text="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus sapien justo, mattis a laoreet nec, dictum non tortor. Vestibulum varius aliquam accumsan."
                    TextColor="LightGray"
                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                    VerticalTextAlignment="Center" />

                <Frame
                    Grid.Row="4"
                    Grid.Column="0"
                    Grid.ColumnSpan="5"
                    Padding="5"
                    BackgroundColor="Blue"
                    CornerRadius="20"
                    HorizontalOptions="Center"
                    VerticalOptions="Center">
                    <Label
                        Margin="10,0,10,0"
                        HorizontalOptions="Center"
                        Text="Available"
                        TextColor="White"
                        VerticalOptions="Center" />
                </Frame>
            </Grid>

            <Button
                Margin="20,20,20,20"
                BackgroundColor="White"
                BorderColor="Blue"
                BorderWidth="1"
                Command="{Binding AddReviewCommand}"
                FontFamily="SFProTextRegular"
                HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                Text="Add Review"
                TextColor="Black" />
        </StackLayout>
    </RefreshView>
</ScrollView>
```

These are the are the target frameworks in the CSPROJ of when running .NET MAUI 6:

```
<TargetFrameworks>net6.0-android;net6.0-ios;net6.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
    <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net6.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

These are the are the target frameworks in the CSPROJ of when running .NET MAUI 7:

```
<TargetFrameworks>net7.0-android;net7.0-ios;net7.0-maccatalyst</TargetFrameworks>
    <TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net7.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

This is just a sample, there are more pages with issues where I would have to rewrite them from scratch. Is this normal or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Seems the order of the 2 at the top should be reversed: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74841495/scrollview-doesnt-work-in-refreshview-net-maui

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is: no, you should not have to rewrite your UI between versions.

Longer answer: however, between versions, especially major versions, bugs will be fixed, or maybe new functionality will be introduced, but this seems more like some bugfix.

If you have been working with .NET 6 and made your UI perfect with that, you might have (unconsciously) worked around a couple of bugs. In the meanwhile, the team has been working on .NET 7, fixing those bugs and when the time comes that you update, suddenly the workarounds now don't work anymore and might show a difference in behavior.

This is certainly not ideal, and overtime as things stabilize that should happen less and less.

For your specific case I see a `Frame` with a `BackgroundColor="White"`, that might be something.

Moreover, instead of a `Frame` you might want to consider using `Border` now which is the spiritual successor and offers some more functionalities.

Hope this answers your question!

Comment: Thank you for the answer Gerald, specially considering that it was one of your videos showcasing the new map features that made me want to upgrade. I'll try to fix the new pages and upgrade. Also, thank you for the great content on YT! : )